# Why do diesel cars not work in Revolution?

Tags: physics, post-apocalyptic, revolution

[Revolution](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2070791/) is a post-apocalyptic TV series, where the main premise is that some sort of technology was used to disable electricity (as in not just the mains but electricity even in batteries doesn't work).

As far as I know not all diesel engines have glowplugs and those that do [can be started if they are not functioning](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xs4TBHWq9k), not to mention that from what I understand, the function of a glowplug could be replicated by heating the car (ie putting it near a fire). In addition diesel engines can be run on straight vegetable oil, which seems pretty useful in a world where fuel pumps no longer work and farming has become common place. And horses (horses are very abundant in the Revolution universe) could be used to roll start larger diesel vehicles.

So why are there no cars at all? Not only that but they go so far as to get a steam train running (note that the tracks had not been used for many years so it's not just locating, moving and servicing a train, it's also servicing the tracks), a seemingly more complex task than roll starting a diesel engine with non functioning glowplugs.

Is there something I'm not getting about real world or in-universe physics here?

**Edit:** I was referring to older model cars which do not use computer/electricity for any of the necessary functions (eg fuel injection). I would like to add to that any homemade device which makes use of a diesel engine, for example a home-made vehicle or a home-made water pump.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible for so many technologies to cease working?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23025/is-it-possible-for-so-many-technologies-to-cease-working)

Comment: I don't think so - this is a good question. A corollary would be why don't we see antique cars driving around? There are plenty of antique cars around, and since they don't have computers in them, they *should* work as well.

Comment: @Thaddeus I think the question is completely different, the other question is asking about whether it's technologically possible to achieve the phenomenon seen in Revolution whilst my question addresses a specific possible in-universe inconsistency.

Comment: @SSumner yeah I generally mean antique diesels, or even home-made vehicles (which still seems easier than getting a steam train to work). I specifically didn't mention petrol engines as they need spark plugs which would need electricity

Comment: There is also no reason for a plane to stop working and then fall straight down, so I think science is not with us here.

Comment: Science does not work the way it should in the Revolution universe. It is likely because the writers did not know diesel technology SHOULD WORK even without electrical power. So the very nature of the technology oppressing electricity defies the laws of physics as we understand them. This question CANNOT be answered except to say THE WRITERS DON'T KNOW SCIENCE. This certainly shouldn't be a surprise to anyone here.

Comment: or they do know but choose to ignore it for plot reasons...

Comment: The real question is why everyone doesn't drop down dead as their ATPsynthase enzyme stops working. Your cells generate power by a current of protons across a membrane. Movement of charged particles is electricity (if a battery stops working, then chemistry isn't working, and the human body runs on chemical power...)

Comment: Let's operate on Clarke's Third Law and assume that they had tech which selectively blocked current from non-biological entities.

Comment: @TheBlindBandit Then where are flesh-clad terminators and cyborgs with implanted computers?

Comment: As the reasoning behind the changes is tied to the 'big secret' of this _open_, still-in-progress series, isn't this almost an _open-ended_ question?  Also, found [this](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/tca-revolution-jj-abrams-eric-kripke-jon-favreau-353668).

Comment: By the way, two weeks ago (episode 1x14) there was a steam-powered bus.  So diesel isn't really necessary.

Comment: Adele almost all planes today are not fly-by-wire - they have electric systems that translate stick and control movements into actuating flaps, ailerons,etc. so the engines would shut down and the pilots would lose all control. Not too much longer after that they would "fall out of the sky". hope someone has an old stearman biplane. Engine still needs spark plugs tho.

Comment: @Tim: I think you mean, almost all planes today _are_ fly-by-wire, which means they're electronically/computer controlled rather than using direct mechanical (hydraulics, cables, etc.) linkages. And this is technically only true of larger planes (airliners, corporate jets, etc.) and military vehicles. And even then, most current fly-by-wire systems are designed to continue operating in the case of full electrical failure. You would lose most instrumentation and possibly aerodynamic assistance, but you still have the ability to manipulate flight surfaces using the the hydraulics.

Comment: The primary exceptions are the most cutting edge military jets like the F-22, which have power-by-wire systems wherein the flight surfaces are not only controlled electrically, but are in fact powered electrically. This lets designers cut down on the weight of the plane by replacing heavy hydraulic systems with lightweight electrical servos.

Answer (score 4):

Extrapolating from other details in *Revolution*, like the scarcity of ammo for hoarded/confiscated automatic weapons, it would be reasonable to assume that the skills, knowledge and manufacturing infrastructure to make a diesel engine, or a steam engine or a flush toilet for that matter, has been lost. So any diesel vehicles would have to be scavenged and as already noted, there aren't that many around today that don't require some kind of electronics.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question they managed to get a steam train running.

Answer (score 0):

Glowplugs (or sparkplugs in Britain and Australia) are only one of the electrical things that a modern car has - fuel is typically pumped from the tank using an electric pump, and practically all cars use ECU computers. So, just because a diesel doesn't need sparkplugs (and some do still use them to heat the fuel) doesn't mean it doesn't need electricity to run.

[Source](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/diesel2.htm)

Comment: a glowplug is not the same as a sparkplug... A glowplug is a hot glowing piece of metal, a spark plug has 2 sharp terminals in between which an electric spark will travel if a strong enough voltage difference is applied between them.

Comment: That doesn't explain why old cars which don't have computers, and there are plenty of those around, aren't being used. Or why home-made go kart-like vehicles don't get used.

Comment: Even old cars without computers still required electricity to work.  But I do agree that you should be able to get an old style diesel with a mechanical fuel pump and a crank start working without any electricity at all.

Comment: @BBlake Yep, kinda like the steam-powered train they had running for a couple episodes.